# Firestore addDoc is not writing data to Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm trying to write some data to my Firestore database. I've been following Firebase docs but for some reason nothing is being written to my database.

It didn't show any console error but just console.log('createPlaylist');
Also, I think firebase has initialized well cause console prints Firestore object properly!

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_apiKey,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_authDomain,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_projectId,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_messagingSenderId,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_appId,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_measurementId,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Cloud Firestore and get a reference to the service
const firebaseDB = getFirestore(app);
if(firebaseDB){
  console.log(firebaseDB)
}
export default firebaseDB;
```

```js
'use client';

import usePlaylistTrackContext from '@/app/create-playlist/PlaylistTrackProvider';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { useState } from 'react';
import firebaseDB from '@/app/firebase/firebasedb';
import { collection, addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import Button from '@/components/Button';

const MyPlaylistTable = () => {
  const [playlistName, setPlaylistName] = useState('');

  const { playlistTracks, setPlaylistTracks } = usePlaylistTrackContext();

  function deleteTrack(track) {
    const nPlaylistTracks = playlistTracks.filter((items) => items.id !== track.id);
    setPlaylistTracks(nPlaylistTracks);
  }

  async function createPlaylist() {
    try {
      console.log('createPlaylist');
      const docRef = await addDoc(collection(firebaseDB, 'playlists'),{
        playlistName: playlistName,
        tracks: playlistTracks,
      });
      console.log('Document written with ID:', docRef.id);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('error adding document', e);
    }
  }

  return (
    <article>
      <div className="flex items-center gap-2 mb-3">
        <input
          className="text-3xl font-bold placeholder-white bg-transparent border-none"
          type="text"
          required
          placeholder="Playlist Title"
          value={playlistName}
          onChange={(e) => setPlaylistName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <Button className="px-2 py-1 text-xs text-bold w-30" onClick={createPlaylist}>
          save
        </Button>
      </div>
      {playlistTracks.map((track) => (
        <div className="relative flex flex-row px-2 py-3" key={track.id}>
          <Image className="mr-3" src={track.img} width={40} height={40} alt="track image" />
          <div>
            <p className="font-bold">{track.name}</p>
            <p className="text-sm font-semibold text-[#B3B3B3]">{track.artist}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="absolute text-right top-5 text-[#B3B3B3] text-sm right-48">
            {Math.floor(track.duration / 60000)}:
            {((track.duration % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0).padStart(2, '0')}
          </div>

          <button className="absolute right-10 top-5" onClick={() => deleteTrack(track)}>
            delete
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </article>
  );
};

export default MyPlaylistTable;
```

I have checked typo and firestore page.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It was a simple problem. I should have to define environment variables using uppercase letters in .env file..